# jQuery ui datepicker as custom date time format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to make a calendar as the image below-

[image]

```
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span id="month">JAN</span><br>
              <span id="day">SAT</span>
           </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span id="date">01</span>
           </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input id="datepicker" type="text">
              <div id="dateoutput"></div>
           </div>


    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'M D dd yy',
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText, inst.settings);
                var dateText1 = $.datepicker.formatDate("D, d M yy", date, inst.settings);
                $("#dateoutput").html("Chosen date is <b>" + dateText1 + "</b>");
            }
        });
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date);
    });
```

By this script I can make custom date format on select, but how can I get this output on page load?

For more -
http://smartmux.com/test/calendar.html

Comment: rather than writing date directly, use a div and few spans to print your data within those spans and for CalendarIcon give a class to the span and apply css

Comment: How I will update those spans with current date?

Comment: do you want to open the calendar on click of icon and then updated the divs? If yes, then in that case it can be done assigning the divs with the texts extracted in onselect event. e.g. `$("#month").html(dateparts[0]);` from my solution given below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this in the onselect method for updating your divs accordingly

```
var dateparts = $.datepicker.formatDate("D, d M yy", date, inst.settings).split(" ");

var shtml = "<div>Depart"+
    "<span>"+ dateparts[0] +"</span>"+
    "<span>"+ dateparts[1] +"</span>"+
    "<span>"+ dateparts[2] +"</span>"+
    "<span class="calendarIcon"></span>"+
"</div>"
$("#dateoutput").html(shtml);
```

and then place the divs and span as you want using css

Comment: Your suggession is working great in onSelect but how can I add it on page load?

Comment: try adding `$('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();` after `$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date);` in document.ready

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", your_Date_here);
});
```